# What are the unknown angles?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

> [image]

I found this problem on facebook. I have tried for hours to solve the problem but could not solve it. My approach is finding the first equation $x+y=30$. But can not find second equation. I am new here. Please help me.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: The thing is, there are multiple solutions. There is not enough information to solve this. Try any $0 < x < 30$: $5, 6, 7$, etc, they all work.

Comment: There is already some discussion and a solution, but is this an isosceles triangle (I'm asking because of the green dashes on the two sides)?

Comment: @dodoturkoz It is an isosceles triangle, but it doesn't need to be assumed. Since $x + y = 30^\circ$, we therefore know that $2x + y = x + 30^\circ$.

Comment: @TheoBendit My bad. Didn't even look at the question properly thinking there was some definition issue. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the sine rule to the three triangles making up the large one to establish

$$\frac{\sin 2x}{\sin 30^\circ}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{\sin(30^\circ-x)}\cdot \frac{\sin(90^\circ-2x)}{\sin30^\circ}=1
$$

which has the solution $x= 12^\circ$, and in turn $y=18^\circ$.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer. But can it be solved with synthetic? I find trigonometry difficult.